# Workbox background sync doesn't run if setting onSync callback

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, background-sync

In my service worker, I'm implementing background sync with workbox like so

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    options => options.url.pathname.startsWith('/api/'),
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
        plugins: [
            new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('myQueueName', {
                maxRetentionTime: 14 * 24 * 60,
                onSync() {
                    showNotification('background sync ran.');
                }
            })]
    }),
    'POST'
);
```

When I test the behavior by disabling network access, executing a request and then turning network access back on, I'm seeing the notification that is triggered in `showNotification`, but I'm not seeing the actual requests.

Oddly enough, when I remove the `onSync` callback, I'm now seeing the requests but obviously, I'm not creating any notifications. How can I get a callback *and* have the actual requests replayed?

Answer (score 3):

I've looked at the implementation of workbox and found the following code:

```
class Queue {
  ...

  constructor(name, {onSync, maxRetentionTime} = {}) {
    ...
    this._onSync = onSync || this.replayRequests;
...
```

and further down

```
_addSyncListener() {
    if ('sync' in registration) {
      self.addEventListener('sync', (event) => {
          ...

          const syncComplete = async () => {
            this._syncInProgress = true;

            let syncError;
            try {
              await this._onSync({queue: this});
```

So as it turns out, when you don't pass an `onSync` callback, the default will be to call `replayRequests`. If you do pass one, you have to do it yourself, e.g. like so

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    options => options.url.pathname.startsWith('/api/'),
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
        plugins: [
            new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('myQueueName', {
                maxRetentionTime: 14 * 24 * 60,
                onSync({ queue }) {
                    // !!! important call here !!!
                    queue.replayRequests(); 
                    showNotification('background sync ran.');
                }
            })]
    }),
    'POST'
);
```